# Python mock issue when mocking a dependency outside a method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

**Scenario 1**

I have the following code I am trying to mock the function `setup_logger()` but if the logger is declared outside the function I am getting an error.

The source file `my_source.py:`

```
from pda.utils.logging import setup_logger


logger = setup_logger()

def some_method():
  some_code
```

The test file `test_my_source.py:`

```
from unittest.mock import patch
import pytest
from src.my_source import some_method

def test_some_method():
    with patch('src.my_source.setup_logger') as mock:
        some_method()
```

In the above scenario, I am getting the below strange errors:

```
_
tests/test_my_source.py:3: in <module>
    from src.my_source import some_method
src/my_source.py:8: in <module>
    logger = setup_logger()
/conda_envs/test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pda/utils/logging.py:79: in setup_logger
    base_conf = get_config()
/conda_envs/test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pda/utils/generics.py:285: in get_config
    tmp_path = os.path.join(tmp_path, name)
/conda_envs/test_env/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py:80: in join
    a = os.fspath(a)
E   TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
=================================================================== short test summary info ====================================================================
ERROR tests/test_my_source.py - TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

**Scenario 2**

If I change the source code and the test then it ***works***. The source file `my_source.py"`

```
from pda.utils.logging import setup_logger


def some_method():
  logger = setup_logger()
  some_code
```

The test file `test_my_source.py:`

```
from unittest.mock import patch
import pytest
from src.my_source import some_method

def test_some_method():
    with patch('src.my_source.setup_logger') as mock:
        some_method()
```

Changing the source code is not an option as in scenario 2 and I have to work with scenario 1. Do I have to modify the test in scenario 1 or what can be the issue?

Comment: The `setup_logger` method would be executed when the module gets imported. Either when you import it or when you try to patch it. I'd suggest trying to mock away the dependencies inside the `setup_logger` method first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the answer from blhsing I fix the issue by patching the method where it is defined like this:

```
def test_some_method():
    with patch('pda.utils.logging.setup_logger') as mock:
        from src.my_source import some_method
        some_method()
```

Alternatively, we can also patch if there is more than one method using:

```
    mock_method1 = mock.patch('pda.utils.logging.setup_logger').start()
    some_method()
    mock_method.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The following line in `my_source.py`:

```
logger = setup_logger()
```

is executed when you import `src.my_source`, before you patch `setup_logger`.

You can instead import `src.my_source` after patching `setup_logger`, but since patching `src.my_source.setup_logger` means to first import `src.my_source` as well, you would need to patch `setup_logger` in the module that defines it, i.e. `pda.utils.logging.setup_logger`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
import pytest

def test_some_method():
    with patch('pda.utils.logging.setup_logger') as mock:
        from src.my_source import some_method
        some_method()
```